# Linear elasticity equations in matlab

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, elasticity

I have a math background but not an engineering background. I am trying to write the equations for linear elasticity in Matlab following the example on a clamped beam [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/examples/dynamic-analysis-of-a-clamped-beam.html).

I mainly want to write the PDE from tensor form into one that I can understand using math notation. The tensor form of the equation is

$\rho \ddot{u}_i - \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k} + \delta_{ik})S_{kj}\right) = f_i$.

Here, $S$ is the second Piola Kirchoff stress tensor with components $S_{11},S_{22},S_{12}$ and $\delta_{ik}$ is the kronecker delta. I understand that the above equation is a vector equation since we have displacement in the $x,y$-directions. Hence, I expect that $i=1$ and $i=2$. But what about the $j,k$ indices? For fixed $i$, do we sum over $j$ and for a fixed $j$, sum over $k$?

This is for a 2d plane stress problem by the way.

Comment: You are familiar with Einstein's summation convention, right?

Comment: No, I'm not. I searched it up but it only gives examples for the case when you have 2 indices. Here, I have 3

Comment: It means you do a double summation over all terms with the indices j and k.  So, j = 1,2,3 and k  = 1,2 3 So there are 9 terms all together.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a double summation sign in front of the right hand side, with j and k both running from 1 to 3.  Einstein's summation convention is shorthand for "sum over repeated indices."

Comment: You mean left-hand side, right? Because there's one equation for $u_1$ and $u_2$. Since this is a 2d plane stress problem, then the summation only runs from 1 to 2?

Comment: For a 2D problem, you sum j and k from 1 to 2.  And, no, I mean the right side.